90’s movie about a creature/alien that gets into guys house through garage using a keypad
Need help finding a movie or tv show I saw on TV, it was horror/sci-fi in the early 90s. This movie or show ABSOLUTELY TERRIFIED me when I was young!! The one scene I remember vividly is of a creature  trying to get into a man’s house. There was a closeup of the creatures fingers pressing a code into a keypad to get into the garage of the man’s house. This part I remember so vividly because there was a closeup of the creatures nails pressing buttons, and the garage door opening slowly. The next I remember is the guy trying to hide from this thing possibly crawling and ending up in a closet at some point. I know he was very afraid of whatever it was. I know there was a fire of some sort involved in this movie maybe the creature burning . The setting was either daytime or a foggy night. I don’t remember 100% but I do know that it involved a garage door or some rising door revealing the creature! That is the part that stands out to me the most!! This movie or show was no later than 1996 and most likely early 90s cause I saw it on tv around 1995. I’ve been searching for this for years!

Was this show in English? And in what country did you watch it?

Yes English and in the United States. Aired on tv around 1994-1995 so if it was a movie could have been released a little earlier than that.
